# How to determine an elite proxy...?

Tags: language-agnostic, proxy

How does one programmatically determine if a given proxy is elite?

What is the general method/headers checked for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to send an HTTP request to yourself, via the proxy. Make the request something uniquely identifiable... perhaps with a dummy query string with a unique signature.

Then, check the access log for the request. Did the request appear to come from your own IP address? If so, the proxy is not elite. Otherwise... it is!

Answer (score 0):

It's my experience that you can't detect elite proxy use from HTTP response headers. In the case of onion routers, the header will show you an IP address that makes it seem as if the traffic originated from the onion router's exit node. And w/r/t Tor, which i would imagine is the most widely used onion router, **Tor [publishes](https://www.torproject.org/tordnsel/) their exit nodes** and allow it to be accessed via API. I know that some Sites access this list and then block any IP address originating from it.